# How to load/bundle static css files with webpack

Tags: css, angularjs, webpack

I have successfully scaffolded my Angular project using Webpack. All JS functionality seems to be included in bundle.js and all of my dynamic CSS is compiling and is accessible by linking to `./styles/main.css`.

My problem is that I have about 10 static CSS files that need to be linked to a well. I know I can hard-code a `<link>` tag for each of them into the HTML page where I bootstrap my Angular app, but I believe there is a way to minify and combine all of these files into something like `/styles/bundle.css`, which I could then link to in my static HTML... or possibly combine them with the contents of `/styles/main.css`, which I'm already linking to.

Is this possible?

Here is the `loaders` JSON from my webpack.config.js:

```
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|externals)/,
        cacheable: true,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: 'es2015',
            //optional: ['runtime', 'es7.asyncFunctions'],
            //retainLines: true,
            cacheDirectory: true
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'transform/cacheable?brfs!transform/cacheable?envify',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|externals)/,
        cacheable: true
    }, {
        //test: /\.css$/,
        //loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader') },

        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        cacheable: true
            //exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
    }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap',
        cacheable: true,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|externals)/
    }, {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        // Passing indentedSyntax query param to node-sass
        loader: 'style!css!sass?indentedSyntax&sourceMap',
        cacheable: true,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|externals)/
    }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'style!css!less?strictMath&noIeCompat',
        cacheable: true,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|externals)/
    }, {
        test: /\.html$/,
        cacheable: true,
        loader: 'html',
        query: {
            attrs: false // indicates that image src should not be processed
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.json$/,
        cacheable: true,
        loader: 'json'
    }, {
        test: /\.woff/,
        loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
    }, {
        test: /\.ttf/,
        loader: 'file?prefix=font/'
    }, {
        test: /\.eot/,
        loader: 'file?prefix=font/'
    }, {
        test: /\.svg/,
        loader: 'file?prefix=font/'
    }]
```

Comment: why did you comment the extractText plugin? use that and require your css files in your webpack modules

Comment: I tried using the plugin as the loader and requiring one of the 10 static CSS files in `/scripts/main.js` but none of the styles defined in that file were available in the page so I thought I was going in the wrong direction. In order to use the plugin, do i need to define some values in a `entry {}`? Couldn't figure that part out or tell if it was even applicable.

Comment: when you require the the css inside of the JS as in 
require './styles/file.css' webpack will bundle that into the JS the idea of the plugin is to take that css and extract it into a bundled.css file that you can then link to

Comment: It sounds like I have to require each file separately. Is there no way to point to an entire directory? Where is the bundled file saved and is it named `bundle.css` or something different?

Comment: Now I'm getting "ReferenceError: ExtractTextPlugin is not defined" resulting from the line in the plugins section: `new ExtractTextPlugin("css/style.css")`. Does it need to be required i some module or something?

Comment: yes you have this https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin

Comment: Right, so `npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin --save` or do I need to pull something from git into my tree? I've done the former... same results.

Comment: you must be missing  `var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");`

Comment: That was it indeed! If you want to add it as an answer (so you get credit for it), I will accept it. Otherwise, I'll do it.

Comment: 1 last question - is there a way to include all CSS files in a given directory so that I don't have to do a `require(./styles/[stylesheet].css)` for each individual file?

Comment: not like that but you can do something like `require('glob').sync(''./styles/*.css).forEach(file=> require(file))`. Explained: glob is a module like many that takes a vinyl pattern and allows you to perform operations over the results in this case will go to styles folder and return the files.css inside it as an array of files. then forEach will iterate over that array and require every file. This code is a sample might not work 100% also you need to `npm install glob --save`.